# JSON.NET - Deserialize not working correctly

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net, deserialization

I want to deserialize a response from `RestResponse` in C# (MAUI).

```cs
request.AddBody(body);
RestResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);
if (response.IsSuccessful)
{
    var list1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(response.Content);
}
```

Here, inside the `if` block the response I want in a list of objects but this line is not executing I mean it never comes to the end statement of the `if` block. What to do? There are so many answers available for this but I tried so many of them, did not work for me. All are saying to do it like this:

```cs
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(response.Content)
```

I initially put my class name `List<MyClassName>` then thought about how would the deserializer know the members so replaced it with just object. No Luck!

Please have look at the response:

```
"{\"documents\":[{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f5cb70d319f7bb78a6e0d\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"UserId\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"Email\":\"abc\",\"Pass\":\"dgdfgdfh\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f5d3a0d319f7bb78a6e0e\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"UserId\":{\"$numberInt\":\"3\"},\"Email\":\"abcd\",\"Pass\":\"dgdgdfh\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f5d900d319f7bb78a6e10\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"UserId\":{\"$numberInt\":\"4\"},\"Email\":\"abcde\",\"Pass\":\"dfgdfhdfhh\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f5db80d319f7bb78a6e11\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"UserId\":{\"$numberInt\":\"5\"},\"Email\":\"abcdef\",\"Pass\":\"dfhjlfdkjh\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f5e170d319f7bb78a6e13\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"0\"},\"UserId\":{\"$numberInt\":\"1\"},\"Email\":\"fhdfhg\",\"Pass\":\"ch\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"639f79a373de576753175098\"},\"Email\":\"admin\"},{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"63a027f853fa7d5e3456d224\"},\"Role\":{\"$numberInt\":\"2\"},\"Email\":\"abc@gmail.com\",\"Pass\":\"12gfgh3a\"}]}"
```

or you may look at this (same):

```
{
    "documents":
    [
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f5cb70d319f7bb78a6e0d"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "UserId":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "Email": "abc",
            "Pass": "fhddfh"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f5d3a0d319f7bb78a6e0e"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "UserId":
            {
                "$numberInt": "3"
            },
            "Email": "abcd",
            "Pass": "dfhfdh"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f5d900d319f7bb78a6e10"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "UserId":
            {
                "$numberInt": "4"
            },
            "Email": "shiva",
            "Pass": "fgsdgsdg"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f5db80d319f7bb78a6e11"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "UserId":
            {
                "$numberInt": "5"
            },
            "Email": "abcdef",
            "Pass": "dfgsdfgsdg"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f5e170d319f7bb78a6e13"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "0"
            },
            "UserId":
            {
                "$numberInt": "1"
            },
            "Email": "abcdefg",
            "Pass": "dgsdgch"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "639f79a373de576753175098"
            },
            "Email": "admin"
        },
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "$oid": "63a027f853fa7d5e3456d224"
            },
            "Role":
            {
                "$numberInt": "2"
            },
            "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "Pass": "12gfgh3a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't even execute the line you need, probably `response.IsSuccessful` is false.

Comment: Nope. I checked by putting the breakpoint it comes inside the if block

Comment: Why then do you say that line isn't executed? If it comes into the if block, it comes to the deserializing line.

Comment: Nope that's the strange thing after coming to that line it never comes to next statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON content is an object with contains the `documents` property which is an array type.

You should deserialize the `response.Content` as the root object and extract the `documents` array.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var root = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
var list1 = (root["documents"] as JArray).ToObject<List<object>>();
```

---

Alternative: Define the `Root` class and deserialize as `Root` object.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("documents")]
    public List<object> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var root = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
var list1 = root.Documents;
```

---

**Updated**

The *syntax* in the attached JSON is MongoDB BsonDocument. I would suggest using *MongoDB.Bson* library to deserialize the response.

```cs
public class Root
{
    [BsonElement("documents")]
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }   
}

public class Document
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Pass { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

Root root = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(response.Content);
var list1 = root.Documents;
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/10L2aI)

Comment: I like the Linq one. Could you please tell me how to get the object member and value by using Foreach. I am s new to this please help me.

Comment: Now it coming like this-
{{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "639f5cb70d319f7bb78a6e0d"
  },
  "Role": {
    "$numberInt": "2"
  },
  "UserId": {
    "$numberInt": "2"
  },
  "Email": "abcd",
  "Pass": "sdgsdgg"
}}

So how do i get to my object !

Comment: Hi, your JSON response for me is the MongoDB BsonDocument. Should deserialize with *MongoDB.Bson*. Check out my latest answer.

Comment: You are Great man. You have saved me finally. This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

From your json input, you can have a respective model class. Use any online tools to convert to `c# class model` objects, i have used [https://json2csharp.com/](https://this) and below is class model output,

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
    public class Document
    {
        public Id _id { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public UserId UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Pass { get; set; }
    }

    public class Id
    {
        [JsonProperty("$oid")]
        public string oid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Role
    {
        [JsonProperty("$numberInt")]
        public string numberInt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Document> documents { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserId
    {
        [JsonProperty("$numberInt")]
        public string numberInt { get; set; }
    }
```

then deserialize the object like

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(response.Content);
```

Comment: This might work one little problem is that for every classes I would have to generate separate classes like this. isn't it!